# order of constructor - chain inheritance

Tags: c++

I run the program below  and after the first line of main I got this output:

> 1
>   6
>   1
>   6
>   13

Could anyone explain why it enters the constructors of `Grand` and `Father` twice?

```
//base class 
class Grand{
public:
    Grand(){cout<<"1"<<endl;}
    Grand(const Grand & g){cout<<"2"<<endl;}
    virtual ~Grand  (){cout<<"3"<<endl;}
    virtual void fun1(Grand g){cout<<"4"<<endl;}
    virtual void fun3(){cout<<"5"<<endl;}
private:
    int m_x;
    };



//derived class 
    class Father: public Grand{
    public:
        Father(){cout<<"6"<<endl;}
        Father(const Father & f){cout<<"7"<<endl;}
        ~Father(){cout<<"8"<<endl;}
        void fun1(){cout<<"9"<<endl;}
        void fun2(Father & f){
            cout<<"10";
            f.fun3();
        }
        void fun3(){
            cout<<"11"<<endl;
        }
        virtual void fun4(){
            cout<<"12"<<endl;
        }
    };


sing namespace std;

//derived class 
        class Son: public Father{
        public:
            Son(){cout<<"13"<<endl;}
            Son(const Son& s){cout<<"14"<<endl;}
            ~Son(){cout<<"15"<<endl;}
            void fun3(){cout<<"16"<<endl;}
            virtual void fun5(Son& s){
                cout<<"17"<<endl;
                s.fun1();
            }
        private:
            Father m_f;
            };

int main(){
Grand * pGrand= new Son; 
.........
.........
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Because you both inherited from Father and instantiated a member of type Father, so now Son has two Father objects- the direct base, and a member.

Comment: I need to think about what you said for 2 min...mm

Comment: @Shiran Another point of interest is this: In your design, any `Father` is also a `Grand` and any `Son` is also a `Father` and (transitively) a `Grand`. Because inheritance in C++ means an "is-a" relationship. This probably doesn't match what you are trying to model.

Comment: Is there one copy of Father's members or two copies ? because you said that there is one father object - the direct base and one which is a member of son.. Can you elaborate on that please ?

Comment: @Shiran: There are two copies. One copy in the `Father` base-class sub-object and one in the `Father` member sub-object.